# how insert large data to MySQL database without change max_allowed_packet

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert, large-data

i have a text bigger than `max_allowed_packet` (1MB)
why i cant insert the data with below code?

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost', 'root', '5u4f1d');

$db->exec('SET NAMES utf8');

$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT `book` (`text`) VALUES (?)');
$tx = file_get_contents('./test.html');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $tx, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

$db->beginTransaction();
$stmt->execute();
$db->commit();
```

It says: `Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference`, but I copy the code from:
 - http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php

db struct:

```
CREATE TABLE `book`
(`text` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: does file_get_contents return any values or is it empty ?

Comment: @Zlatan Yes it return the large text.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost', 'root', '5u4f1d');

$db->exec('SET NAMES utf8');

$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT `book` (`text`) VALUES (?)');

// note the "fopen" function, not file_get_contents
$tx = fopen('test.html', 'rb');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $tx, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

$db->beginTransaction();
$stmt->execute();
$db->commit();
```

Also on:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php

It is pointed out that:

> ... binds the LOB into the variable named $lob and then sends it to
>   the browser using fpassthru(). Since the LOB is represented as a
>   stream, functions such as fgets(), fread() and stream_get_contents()
>   can be used on it.

Also, try changing your "text" table field into BLOB data-type like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `book`
(`text` BLOB NOT NULL)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: no it does not solve the problem. what you quote about `fpassthru` is about SELECT (read) not INSERT

Comment: yes i try to solve the problem with `$tx = fopen('test.html', 'rb');` instead of `$tx = file_get_contents('./test.html');` but the problem not solved.

Comment: is your 'text' field in the table of "BLOB" data type, or it is of 'TEXT' ?

Comment: I've changed my answer post. change about your table layout.. please change your table text field into BLOB, try with that configuration.. if it works, accept and rate up my answer :) thanks !